# MySQL - Finding Empty relations

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to work out how to get a full list of team leaders and team members from our tables. *Including* those team leaders who have no team.

We have a basic data structure where we have a table `person` which contains our basic person object. For certain people we extend this table with in a `details` table.

One of the extended pieces of information that we have is team_leader status. We have two relevant details that define this: `detail_isTeamLeader` and `detail_teamLeader`. 
The first is a boolean and defines a short list of team leaders. The second defines who a persons team leader is (ideally from the subset).

```
_person table_
person_id
person_name

_detail table_
detail_id
detail_person_id
detail_isTeamLeader
detail_teamLeader
```

I can get all the team leaders who have a team using the following Query:

```
SELECT tl.person_id AS tlref, tl.person_name AS tlname, 
per.person_id AS perref, per.person_name AS pername
FROM detail
LEFT OUTER JOIN person AS per ON detail.person = per.person_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN person AS tl ON detail_teamleader = tl.person_id
ORDER BY tlname, psname
```

However, this fails for those team_leaders where `detail.isTeamLeader` is true but do not occur in the `detail_teamLeader` field.

Sample Data

```
person_id   person_name
1           Joe Bloggs
2           Fred Smith
3           Frank Jones
4           Amy Kelly

detail_id   detail_person_id   detail_isTeamLeader   detail_teamLeader
1           1                  1                     0
2           2                  1                     0
3           3                  0                     3 
4           4                  0                     3
```

In the example above Joe and Fred are Team Leaders. However, Joe has no-one in his team, and in the query above is therefore omitted from the result set.

I suspect that normalizing the data structure might be the best answer, but is there a way without doing this?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help convey the issue you are having.

Comment: If you extend a person table, a) the detail table should have the person_id as primary key, and b) you should always start at the person table and left join from there (or use a right join).

Comment: Have added an example of the data, and clarified that `detail_person` is a key to `person_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you have a 1 to 1 relationship between the persons and details but not all persons have detail information.

I'm not sure if you want to get only the team leaders with all persons in their team (including the ones that don't have a team), or you want a dataset with all persons with their team leader information.

In the first case you would have to use an inner select (or CTE in Sql server) to select all your team leaders and join that with details and persons tables. Here's the query you could use:

```
select tl.person_id as tlref, tl.name as tlname, p.person_id as perref, p.name as pername 
from (
        select p.person_id,p.name 
        from @persons p 
        inner join @details d on d.person_id = p.person_id and d.is_temamleader = 1
) tl
left outer join @details d on d.team_leader = tl.person_id
left join @persons p on p.person_id = d.person_id
```

For the second case (getting all persons with their team leader information):

```
select p.person_id as perref, p.name as pername, d.is_teamleader,  pTl.person_id as tlref, ptl.name as tlname
from @persons p
left outer join @details d on d.person_id = p.person_id
left outer join @persons pTl on pTl.person_id = d.team_leader
```

I suspect the first query is what you were asking for but I added the second one just in case you need it. Please note that I used table variables (@persons, @details) so replace those with your actual table names.

Comment: The first is indeed what I need. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If You need all team leaders and all records from table 'person' have 
corresponding record in table 'detail' I think You can use this code:

```
SELECT
  person_id, person_name
FROM
  person
LEFT JOIN
  detail 
ON 
  person.person_id = detail.person
WHERE
  detail.detail_isTeamLeader = 1
```